# How to keep file's directory (or nearest .git directory) when running :sh :shell

Tags: shell, vim

Is there any way how to use :sh to open shell in needed directory? So I don't have to use cd to get directory I need. Running something like :sh /your/directory does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just wanting to run your shell in the directory of the file you're editing you could `set autochdir` - it automatically changes directory to whatever file you are editing.

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but I don't know of any built in way to do that.  Though you could write a function to do it.  Something like this does the trick for me:

```
function ShellCd(path)
    cd `=a:path`
    shell
endfunction
```

Of course the directory will remain changed after you've ran your shell, but it may be possible to change the function to not do that.